# Understanding UIScrollView contentSize.height

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I'm kind of confused by this. I have a very simple setup. I have a UIScrollView that is constrained to the superview of a ViewController with 0,0,0,0. And then a UILabel that is constrained to the UIScrollView with 8,8,8,8.

I have a String extension to get the height of the label with a specific font.

```
extension String {
    func heightWithConstrainedWidth(width: CGFloat, font: UIFont) -> CGFloat {
        let constraintRect = CGSize(width: width, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude)
        let boundingBox = self.boundingRect(with: constraintRect, options: [.usesLineFragmentOrigin, .usesFontLeading], attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: font], context: nil)
        return boundingBox.height
    }
}
```

In viewDidLoad, I set up my label. (UILabel is set for number of lines to 0 and word wrap).

```
let text = "some really long text" // actually really long text in my sample
let width = view.frame.width
let font: UIFont! = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-UltraLight", size: 42)
let height = text.heightWithConstrainedWidth(width: width, font: font)
print("height first: \(height)") // 1080
```

Then I set my scrollView.contentSize to that size

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height)
print("new height: \(scrollView.contentSize.height)") // 1080
```

But in scrollViewDidScroll, if I print out the height there

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    print("scrollView.contentSize.height: \(scrollView.contentSize.height)") // 3440
}
```

I was wondering why in scrollViewDidScroll the height of the scrollView's contentSize is 3440 and not 1080. It's 1080 after I put in the text for the label and set up the content size.

I would think if the size is 3440, I would see that after I set the scrollView's contentSize and it wouldn't change in the scrollViewDidScroll delegate method. Is this because I'm using Auto Layout and Auto Layout doesn't calculate the size of the contentSize until you start scrolling or something?

Comment: There isn't any auto layout anywhere in your code?

Comment: @bsod the autolayout is in Interface Builder

Comment: And why are you setting the scroll view's content size?

Comment: @bsod because I'm setting my text dynamically in viewDidLoad. It's long so I thought I could set it in viewDidLoad. Should I be setting my constraints in code after the setting of the text in order to get more deterministic behavior?

Comment: When you use pure auto layout with a scroll view, you don't touch any view's frame property (constraints do that) and you don't set the scroll view's content size (it's effectively treated as a ready-only property).

Comment: If your label is properly constrained using auto layout, you can change its text whenever and the UI will adapt accordingly.

Comment: @bsod the label does adapt accordingly how I want. But I'm confused on how the sizes get calculated. Like why after I set the label, the height is 1080, but in scrollViewDidScroll, it's 3440. That's what my question is.

Comment: But why are you setting the scroll view's content size if auto layout is handling everything?

Comment: @bsod. I guess that's a mistake then. Just learning.